# Javascript Efficiency

Tags: javascript, coding-efficiency

I have been working on my ability to program in Javascript. One of the concerns that I have is that my code works but I don't know if it is efficient. I feel like I keep working around problems rather than solving them properly. For example:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  for(var i = 0; i<words.length;i++){
    words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
    letters = words[i].split('');
    letters[0] = letters[0].toUpperCase();
    word = letters.join('');
    words[i] = word;
  }
  str = words.toString().replace(/,/g," ");
  console.log(str);
  return str;
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

I feel like there has to be a better way to do things. Does anyone have any suggestions on 1) How to learn more efficient ways of doing things 2) How would you clean this code up?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Check out [CodeReview.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Vote to close because question is more suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Instead of the code from `letters = words[i].split('');` to `words[i] = word;`, you could’ve simply written `words[i][0] = words[i][0].toUpperCase();`. No need to split a string to access its letters. Also instead of `words.toString().replace(/,/g," ");` use `words = words.join(" ")`.

Comment: @Xufox you cannot do `words[i][0] = words[i][0].toUpperCase();`. Strings are immutable.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Whoops, you’re right. `words[i] = words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1);` would work.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't worry about efficiency in term of the speed of your program until you notice it being a problem.

In terms of clean code and readability, higher-order functions are generally better than for loops:

```
function titleCase (string) {
  return string.split(' ').map(function(word) {
    return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)
  }).join(' ');
}
```

Or even quicker in ES6:

```
const titleCase = (str) => 
  str.split(' ')
  .map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
  .join(' ')
```

Comment: To make things even more "official", use `.charAt(0)` instead of `[0]`